# How to bundle webpacker-aware javascript inside a gem

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5.1, webpacker

Is there already a 'best practice' for bundling webpacker-aware javascript code and dependencies in a gem?

I have gem consisting of ruby code and accompanying javascript, the two are pretty entangled.

In the best world, we'd `export` something in the gem and `import` it in the app. But I don't currently have a clue on how that can be achieved.

The `package.json` dependencies of the gem would need to be resolved in the app, too.

Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: I am also really curious about that. Maybe the `babel-plugin-module-resolver` is a starting point. Couldn't find any blog posts and how-tos yet.

Comment: Also linking a similar issue at rails/webpacker here https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/488